# Deleting the contents from log file in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008, file, logging, delete-file

The log file is completely filled, now I have increased the size of the log file by some size for time being, further there is no space left. I want the contents of the log file deleted.
If I change the mode of the db from full to simple, will it delete the log contents or stop adding the log details?

Answer (score 2):

You can shrink

```
Use DatabaseName
dbcc SHRINKFILE (logFilenName, size)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shrink the log with the following Statements:

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT
DBCC SHRINKFILE([MyDatabase_log], 1)
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET RECOVERY FULL WITH NO_WAIT
GO
```

This snippet can be found on various sites in the net, but be aware that it's not a good practice to kill the log like this because of recovery. After doing this, you can only recover your database to the last full or full+incremental backup.